# Phone number Validation Code

Tags: jquery, validation, jsp, phone-number

Can somebody help me to validate these phone number patterns?
Please see the image below to help me solve my problems..
I couldnt figure any way to do it as i am new to validation.
Any help is appreciated..
Thanks

I am sorry i couldnt post the image.
the format is +97798********

Comment: where is the image?

Comment: you can use regular expression for the phone number validation. Here's the regular expression 
`\+([0-9]){13}`

Comment: hey i edited my post>>check it out!

Comment: @noodlesegg i am familiar with the common regexp. Just need the specific code for my format so :)

Comment: this code is for js
`var phoneNumber = '+97798********';`
`var match = phoneNumber.match(/\+([0-9]){13}/);`

Comment: You should consider adding the code you have tried to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Cleave JS**](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) which helps you to validate and format the phone numbers in a more meaningful way, you can do it like this:

See [Demo Here](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/)

```
var cleave = new Cleave('.input-element', {
    phone: true,
    phoneRegionCode: 'IN'
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please demonstrate how to actually use it in input field and what things to import @saumya Rastogi